# How can I set the file output location in ogr2ogr?

Tags: ogr2ogr

Whenever I use ogr2ogr to convert files the output is saved to the following directory:

**C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Local\VirtualStore**

Is there anyway I can set this directory to something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the output file location by adding it to the ogr2ogr command arguments; for example:

```
ogr2ogr -f geoJSON -s_srs EPSG:27700 -t_srs EPSG:4326 c://somedirectory/outputfilename inputfilename
```